# How to open google maps with multiple stops in web app?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is what i use for opening google maps for a single stop :

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    const location = "Empire state building"
    const location2 = "Washington square park"

var url = `https://www.google.com.sa/maps/search/${location}?hl=en`

window.open(url, '_blank');

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button>OPEN GOOGLE MAPS</button>
</body>
</html>
```

How could i include `location2` in the url to make a multiple stop route?

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple stops via the following format:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/${START}/${STOP1}/${STOP2}/${END}`.

You can add as many stops as you want.

Comment: cool,do you know how can i automatically set START as CURRENT LOCATION ?

Comment: @VaggelisNos you can leave start empty so the user can enter it themselves. Like: `https://www.google.com/maps/dir//${STOP1}/${STOP2}/${END}`. Note the double `/`